# Images won't show right under the navigation bar

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a problem with showing my carousel under the navigation bar

I have made a function that creates an images carousel with a fade effect that transitions automatically without user interaction, and when I'm trying to make it display under the navigation bar and cover all the body using CSS properties like 'Z-index' it doesn't work

Here is my Component and my Css

```
import React from 'react'
import '../Styling/Home.css'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import img1 from '../Media/containerPic1.jpg'
import img2 from '../Media/containerPic2.jpg'
import img3 from '../Media/ContainerPic3.jpg'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import logo from '../Media/anamehani-logo-ar.png'



 
    function Home() {
        const images=[ img1, img2, img3];
        const[CurrentImageIndex, setCurretImageIndex]= useState(0);

    useEffect(() =>{
        const interval= setInterval(()=>{
            setCurretImageIndex((prevIndex) =>(prevIndex+1) % images.length);
        },3000);
        return()=>{
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, [images]);
    
  return (
    <>
    <div className='Header'>
      <NavLink to="/"><img src={logo} className='logo-img'  alt='logo'/></NavLink>  
    <NavLink className="nav-link" activeclassname="nav-link-active" to="/"> <h2> الرئيسية</h2>  </NavLink>
    <NavLink className="nav-link" activeclassname="nav-link-active" to="/home2"> <h2> خدمات</h2>  </NavLink>
    <NavLink className="nav-link" activeclassname="nav-link-active" to="/"> <h2> اعلانات</h2>  </NavLink>
    <NavLink className="nav-link" activeclassname="nav-link-active" to="/"> <h2> الصفقات</h2>  </NavLink>
    <NavLink className="nav-link" activeclassname="nav-link-active" to="/"> <h2> تواصل معنا</h2>  </NavLink>
    <NavLink className="nav-link" activeclassname="nav-link-active" to="/"> <h2> تسجيل الدخول</h2>  </NavLink>
   <NavLink  to="/"> <button className="create-btn"> انشاء حساب</button> </NavLink>
</div>
    <div className='container'>
        {images.map((image, index) =>(
            <img
            key={index}
            src={image}
            alt={'Image'+ (index+1)} 
            className={'car-image' +(index === CurrentImageIndex ? 'active' :'')}
            />
        ))}
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
export default Home
```

My Css:

```
.Header {
    display: flex ;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    direction: rtl;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 12px;
    z-index: 2;


}
 .nav-link{
    display: inline-block;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 36px;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    z-index: 2;

}
.logo-img{
    width: 140px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 100px ;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 16px;

}
.create-btn{
    padding: 8px 16px;
    background-color: #f8af39;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 900;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    margin-right: 100px;

}

 .container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 678px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;

}
.car-image{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit:cover;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0,5 ease;
}
.car-image .active{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think className of img is not correct. In above case, it is "car-image" or "car-imageactive", and opacity of img is always 0.

className={"car-image"+" "+(index === CurrentImageIndex ? 'active' :'')}